# Get geo locations repeatedly (after every.. 1 minute )

Tags: android, geolocation

I am calling toast message in `AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.class`. how to fetch geo locations after every 1 minutes.. With below code I am getting only once

```
public class AndroidGPSTrackingActivity extends Activity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);



gps = new GPSTracker(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.this);
    // check if GPS enabled
    if (gps.canGetLocation()) {

double       latitude = gps.getLatitude();
double   longitude = gps.getLongitude();
                Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"Your Locion is - \nLat: " + latitude
            + "\nLog: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                 System.out.println("respmaillati::;;"+latitude);



    } else {

        gps.showSettingsAlert();
    }


}
```

in manifest I given

```
<service android:name=".GPSTracker"  />
```

Code:

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

private final Context mContext;

// flag for GPS status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

// flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

// flag for GPS status
boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location; // location
double latitude; // latitude
double longitude; // longitude

// The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 100 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;

public GPSTracker(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();
}

public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            // First get location from Network Provider
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}

/**
 * Stop using GPS listener
 * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
 * */
public void stopUsingGPS(){
    if(locationManager != null){
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
    }       
}

/**
 * Function to get latitude
 * */
public double getLatitude(){
    if(location != null){
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }
    System.out.println("responsel:::"+latitude);
    // return latitude
    return latitude;
}

/**
 * Function to get longitude
 * */
public double getLongitude(){
    if(location != null){
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    // return longitude


    System.out.println("responsel:::"+longitude);


    return longitude;
}

/**
 * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
 * @return boolean
 * */
public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

/**
 * Function to show settings alert dialog
 * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
 * */
public void showSettingsAlert(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

}
```

Comment: In onLocationChanged(Location location) method you will get the new lat lng put toast in this method.

Comment: Thanks for reply YSL... only once it showed toast but i want every one minute

Comment: location manager will automatically send you updates for every 1min and 10meters.
This line is enough:
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

Comment: if you want for every 1 min only then change 10m to 0m

Comment: @Override
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
      // Let it continue running until it is stopped.
      Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      return START_STICKY;
   }

Comment: i set 10 m to 0m ...so am getting toast messages every 1 minutes...but latitude and longitude values are same ..not changing..

Comment: did you check the setting of Location(High accuracy) and internet in your phone. In onLocationChanged method you will get lat lng move from one place to another.

Answer (score 0):

Try this! 
Wrap the toast code in a method and call it recursively using Handler and Runnable:

```
public class AndroidGPSTrackingActivity extends Activity {

Handler showLocationHandler;
Runnable showLocationRunnable;
private static final int DELAY_TIME = 1000 * 60; //delay time - 1 minute

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    gps = new GPSTracker(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.this);
    showLocationHandler = new Handler();
    showLocationRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            showLatLongToast();
        }
    };

    //call the method once
    showLatLongToast();
}

public void showLatLongToast() {
    if (gps.canGetLocation()) {

        double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
        double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Locion is - \nLat: " + latitude
                + "\nLog: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        System.out.println("respmaillati::;;" + latitude);


    } else {

        gps.showSettingsAlert();
    }
    //call the same method after some delay
    showLocationHandler.postDelayed(showLocationRunnable, DELAY_TIME);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    //kill this runnable when ever you want to stop displaying toast like this
    showLocationHandler.removeCallbacks(showLocationRunnable);
    }
}
```